# Why I get error Invalid identifier since column exist

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have SELECT statment like this

```
SELECT          a.ATAID, 
                a.ataComment, 
                a.Type, 
                a.AtaNumber, 
                a.DeviationNumber, 
                a.ProjectID, 
                a.Name, 
                a.StartDate, 
                a.DueDate, 
                a.RevisionDate, 
                a.Status, 
                a.Ata, 
                a.Deviation,
                a.Locked, 
                a.PaymentType, 
                a.BecomeExternalAtaFromInternal, 
                a.Author, 
                a.AtaType, 
                a.DeviationType, 
                a.PDFUrl, 
                a.street, 
                a.city, 
                a.zip, 
                a.briefDescription, 
                a.ConfirmStatus, 
                a.Token, 
                a.ParentAta, 
                a.EmailSent, 
                a.ClientComment, 
                a.AnswerEmail, 
                a.AnswerTime, 
                a.UserID, 
                a.FromFortnox, 
                a.ForFortnox, 
                a.client_answer_attachment, 
                debitform.Name as paymentTypeName, 
                CONCAT(CONCAT(users.Surname, ' '),users.Lastname) AS AuthorName, 
                NULL AS Description, 
                NULL AS Reason, 
                NULL AS Suggestion, 
                NULL AS State, 
                'ata' as AtaTable , 
                NULL AS WeeklyReports,
                NULL AS Attachment,
                NULL AS articlesAdditionalWorkFromia, 
                NULL AS enabledAccounts, 
                NULL AS DefaultWeeklyReports, 
                NULL AS articlesMaterialFromia, 
                NULL AS articlesOtherFromia,
                NULL AS WeeklyReportsMomentsPerWeek,
                a.becomeFastFromOtherType,
                ia.ataComment, 
                 ia.Type, 
                 ia.AtaNumber, 
                 ia.DeviationNumber, 
                 ia.ProjectID, 
                 ia.Name, 
                 ia.StartDate, 
                 ia.DueDate,
                 ia.RevisionDate, 
                 ia.Status, 
                 ia.Ata, 
                 ia.Deviation, 
                 ia.Locked, 
                 ia.PaymentType, 
                 ia.BecomeExternalAtaFromInternal,
                 ia.Author, 
                 ia.AtaType, 
                 ia.DeviationType,
                 ia.PDFUrl, 
                 ia.street, 
                 ia.city, 
                 ia.zip, 
                 ia.briefDescription, 
                 ia.ConfirmStatus, 
                 ia.Token, 
                 ia.ParentAta, 
                 ia.EmailSent, 
                 ia.ClientComment, 
                 ia.AnswerEmail, 
                 ia.AnswerTime, 
                 ia.UserID, 
                 ia.FromFortnox,
                 ia.ForFortnox,
                 ia.client_answer_attachment, 
                 debitform.Name as paymentTypeName,
                 CONCAT(CONCAT(users.Surname, ' '),users.Lastname) AS AuthorName,
                 ia.Description, 
                 ia.Reason, 
                 ia.Suggestion, 
                 ia.State, 
                 'ata_become_external' as AtaTable,
                 ia.WeeklyReports, 
                 ia.Documents AS Attachment, 
                 ia.articlesAdditionalWork AS articlesAdditionalWorkFromia, 
                 ia.enabledAccounts, 
                 ia.DefaultWeeklyReports, 
                 ia.articlesMaterial AS articlesMaterialFromia, 
                 ia.articlesOther AS articlesOtherFromia, 
                 ia.WeeklyReportsMomentsPerWeek,
                 NULL AS becomeFastFromOtherType
FROM 
                  ata a
LEFT JOIN
                  users
INNER JOIN       internal_atas ia 
ON               (a.ATAID = ia.ATAID AND a.Author = users.UserID)
LEFT JOIN
                 debitform
ON
                  debitform.Id = a.PaymentType
WHERE 
                 
                  a.ATAID = 2095 
OR                ia.ATAID IS NULL
                 
OR 
                 a.ParentAta = 0  OR  ia.ParentAta = 0
GROUP BY         a.ATAID
```

The ATAID is column which exist in table ata

### a.ATAID

```
  2117
  2118
  2119
  2120
  2121
  2122
  2123
```

Also AtaID from another table which is called internal_atas

```
ATAID
no rows selected
```

When I run query I get error message

```
ORA-00904: "A"."ATAID": invalid identifier
```

This line of code throw error

```
ON               a.ATAID = ia.ATAID
```

I try to change this two part and make inversion like

```
ON ia.ATAID = a.ATAID
```

But still have same problem.

What is wrong here ? What I miss ?

Table Definition:

```
internal_atas

ANSWEREMAIL VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
ANSWERTIME  TIMESTAMP(6)
ARTICLESADDITIONALWORK  CLOB
ARTICLESMATERIAL    CLOB
ARTICLESOTHER   CLOB
ATA NUMBER(10,0)
ATABECOMEEXTERNALID NUMBER(10,0)
ATACOMMENT  CLOB
ATAID   NUMBER(10,0)
ATANUMBER   NUMBER(10,0)
ATATYPE VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
AUTHOR  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
BECOMEEXTERNALATAFROMINTERNAL   NUMBER(10,0)
BRIEFDESCRIPTION    CLOB
CITY    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
CLIENT_ANSWER_ATTACHMENT    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
CLIENTCOMMENT   VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
CONFIRMSTATUS   NUMBER(10,0)
DEFAULTWEEKLYREPORTS    CLOB
DESCRIPTION CLOB
DEVIATION   NUMBER(10,0)
DEVIATIONNUMBER VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
DEVIATIONTYPE   VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
DOCUMENTS   CLOB
DUEDATE DATE
EMAILSENT   NUMBER(10,0)
ENABLEDACCOUNTS CLOB
EXTERNALATANUMBER   VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
FORFORTNOX  NUMBER(10,0)
FROMFORTNOX NUMBER(10,0)
INTERNALATANUMBER   VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
IS_DELETED  NUMBER(10,0)
LOCKED  NUMBER(10,0)
NAME    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
PARENTATA   NUMBER(10,0)
PAYMENTTYPE VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
PDFURL  CLOB
PROJECTID   NUMBER(10,0)
QUANTITY    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
REASON  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
REVISIONDATE    VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
STARTDATE   DATE
STATE   CLOB
STATUS  NUMBER(10,0)
STREET  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
SUGGESTION  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
TOKEN   VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
TYPE    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
UNIT    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
USERID  NUMBER(10,0)
WEEKLYREPORTS   CLOB
WEEKLYREPORTSMOMENTSPERWEEK CLOB



ATA


ANSWEREMAIL VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
ANSWERTIME  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
ATA NUMBER(10,0)
ATACOMMENT  CLOB
ATAID   NUMBER(10,0)
ATAINTERNALNUMBER   VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
ATANUMBER   VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
ATATYPE VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
AUTHOR  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
BECOMEATAFROMDEVIATION  NUMBER(10,0)
BECOMEEXTERNALATAFROMINTERNAL   NUMBER(10,0)
BECOMEFASTFROMOTHERTYPE NUMBER(10,0)
BRIEFDESCRIPTION    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
CITY    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
CLIENT_ANSWER_ATTACHMENT    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
CLIENTCOMMENT   VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
CONFIRMSTATUS   NUMBER(10,0)
CREATED_AT  DATE
DEVIATION   NUMBER(10,0)
DEVIATIONNUMBER VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
DEVIATIONTYPE   VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
DUEDATE DATE
EMAILSENT   NUMBER(10,0)
FINANCEID   NUMBER(10,0)
FORFORTNOX  NUMBER(10,0)
FROMFORTNOX NUMBER(10,0)
IS_DELETED  NUMBER(10,0)
LOCKED  CHAR(1 CHAR)
NAME    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
PARENTATA   NUMBER(10,0)
PAYMENTTYPE NUMBER(10,0)
PDFURL  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
PROJECTID   NUMBER(10,0)
QUANTITY    VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
REASON  VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
REVISIONDATE    DATE
STARTDATE   DATE
STATUS  NUMBER(10,0)
STREET  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
SUGGESTION  VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
TOKEN   VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
TYPE    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
UNIT    VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
```

Since internal_atas table is empty so I dont have any data only in table ata I have data something like

Sorry for separete but I have more then 30 column in table

```
ANSWEREMAIL        ANSWERTIME            ATA   ATACOMMENT  ATAID    ATAINTERNALNUMBER  ATANUMBER    ATATYPE   AUTHOR  BECOMEATAFROMDEVIATION  BECOMEEXTERNALATAFROMINTERNAL     BECOMEFASTFROMOTHERTYPE    BRIEFDESCRIPTION    CITY     
email@email.com    2020-05-04 12:05:18   1      NULL        2036    NULL                3            1        197       0                       0                                   0                       some text here      Zagreb
```

PART II ATA table

```
CLIENT_ANSWER_ATTACHMENT    CONFIRMSTATUS    CREATED_AT         DEVIATION   DEVIATIONTYPE   DUEDATE         EMAILSENT  FINANCEID        FORFORTNOX      FROMFORTNOX     IS_DELETED  LOCKED  NAME         PARENTATA   PAYMENTTYPE
NULL                            1             10-JUN-20             3           1           06-APR-20        1          173                 1           0                0          0       fffttt          0         1
```

PART III

```
PDFURL          PROJECTID    QUANTITY  REASON   REVISIONDATE    STARTDATE      STATUS     STREET             SUGGESTION      TOKEN                        TYPE    UNIT      USERID      ZIP
someurl.com     261             NULL   NULL         NULL         STARTDATE      2          FoxBox 111         NULL           32aacd4b76628feeece6          1       NULL      NULL       2624
```

Comment: This SQL statement is incorrect, you have 2 queries in a row, and in your second query you have 2 times `ON` specified, which might be the root cause of your issue. Maybe you want this: `ON (a.ATAID = ia.ATAID
AND a.Author = users.UserID)`. If not, edit your question and add the real SQL query.

Comment: Could you post tables' descriptions? In SQL*Plus, run e.g. `DESC ata`. By the way, this: `OR ia.ATAID = NULL` is wrong; should be `OR ia.ATAID  IS NULL`

Comment: @Littlefoot I don't have tables description I have only column which is description if you mean.

Comment: ORA-00904 usually means that column you're using doesn't exist in that table. If someone created it using double quotes (e.g. `create table ata("ataid" number)`, then you have to reference it exactly like that every time you use it, e.g. `select "ataid" from ata`. As you said you "see" the column, maybe that's the case, but I can't tell if I can't see table's description.

Comment: Please give me a little bit I will update my question so far. Everything I change but still have problem

Comment: @Littlefoot  I have updated my question. You can check now

Comment: @ThomasG I have alredy update my question. You can check now

Comment: Simplified: what does this return? `select * from ata a left join internal_atas ia on a.ataid = ia.ataid`

Comment: @Littlefoot This works fine. It returns all column from ata and internal_atas

Comment: OK, so what's the difference between that and code you wrote?

Comment: What part of code do you mean which I wrote ? 
You mean SELECT statment ?

Comment: So far I try to use UNION but stil have problem. Hmm

Comment: @Littlefoot Somehow I made this query running by using UNION but the problem is that I have to eliminate couple of column because I get error message like 
`ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns`

Comment: Make sure `no of columns in each union are same` and `compatible data type with each other.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query has a structural issue, i.e. it is written incorrectly. You have the structural element:

```
select ...
FROM 
                  ata a
LEFT JOIN
                  users
INNER JOIN       internal_atas ia 
ON               (a.ATAID = ia.ATAID AND a.Author = users.UserID)
...
```

This is invalid as it translates to the form "from a join b join c on ... on ..." where the join syntax requires the form "from a join b on ... join c on ...". So you need something like:

```
select ...         
  from  ata a
  left join  users  on  a.author = users.userid
  inner join internal_atas ia on  a.ataid = ia.ataid
  ...
```

I believe this is what @ThomasG war referring to.  
I am somewhat surprised at the particular error message you are getting. When I tried your query I got "ORA-00905: missing keyword", but I have long since concluded that when a query contains structurally invalid you can just ignore the specific error message (at that point Oracle is "just guessing") and correct the query, then retry.  

*BTW.* You have an inconsistency in your query as well:

```
ON               (a.ATAID = ia.ATAID AND a.Author = users.UserID)
WHERE        
                  a.ATAID = 2095 
OR                ia.ATAID IS NULL
```

Any row that satisfies the ON (a.ATAID = ia.ATAID) condition cannot also satisfy the OR (ia.ATAID IS NULL). And since it MUST satisfy the ON condition the OR is condition is superfluous. Unless it is changed when structural element is corrected.

**Suposition:**  
There is perhaps a plausible explanation for your error. According to the [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Joins.html#GUID-A7F5091B-9C42-4FC3-8F2B-BB238518FA14)

> To execute a join of three or more tables, Oracle first joins two of
> the tables based on the join conditions comparing their columns and
> then joins the result to another table based on join conditions
> containing columns of the joined tables and the new table. Oracle
> continues this process until all tables are joined into the result.
> The optimizer determines the order in which Oracle joins tables based
> on the join conditions, indexes on the tables, and, any available
> statistics for the tables.
> At that point in the parsing perhaps it is attempting to evaluate

```
users
    INNER JOIN       internal_atas ia 
    ON               (a.ATAID = ia.ATAID AND a.Author = users.UserID)
```

At which point table ata is not part of the evaluation and thus the column is not defined. As I said this is "just a guess on my part", but it seems to fit the evidence.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I solve the problem ! It works now :)